# JBPM 5.2 integration with Spring throws SAXParseException

Tags: xml, spring, jbpm

I have a project that uses Spring 3.0.7 and i'm trying to implelment JBPM 5.2 in it (currently using JBPM 4).
I added code to my mvc-config.xml as specified in the official user guide of JBPM 5.2 but when i run the project it throws this error:

org.xml.sax.SAXParseException : Attribute "schemaLocation" bound to namespace "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" was already specified for element "definitions".

I see it has something to do with xml's namespaces but i have no idea why it is hapenning and how to fix it (i tried to add the content of my mvc-config.xml but the site won't let me because apperantely i don't have enough credit here...)

any help would be greatly appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

I'm kinda guessing here, as I can't see the XML directly, but since it is complaining about the element "definitions", I'm guessing it's an issue with one of your BPMN2 process definitions.  In the definitions element (the root element of your process definition file), you have an attribute schemaLocation, and I would guess that your process has multiple entries for the namespace "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance".  I would guess that you by example copy-pasted one line twice or something like that.